# Use session inside script tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net

my code is

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var control_btn21 = $('.mine'), interval21;

        $.ajax_upload(control_btn21, {
            action: 'FileHandler.ashx',
            name: 'control21',
            onSubmit: function (file, ext) {



                $('#uploadResume').addClass("Uploading");
                disableBtn = true;


                this.disable();

                interval21 = window.setInterval(function () {

                    if (control_btn21.text().length < 13) {
                        //          control_btn21.text(control_btn21.text() + '.');
                    } else {
                        //        control_btn21.text('Uploading');
                    }
                }, 200);
            },
            onComplete: function (file, response) {

                $('#uploadResume').removeClass("Uploading");

                disableBtn = false;
                window.clearInterval(interval21);

                this.enable();

                var file_added = file;

                var path = response;

                path = strip(path);
                alert(path);
                   **<%# Session["path"].ToString() %> = path;**

                $('.pathing').text(path);
                $('.testing').attr("src", "temp/" + path);
            }
        });
    });
```

in this i want to use the session to store the  value of variable **path** but i am not able to do that please help and find what's the actual problem

thanks

Comment: Session is server side storage you're on the client.

Comment: have you inherits these IRequiresSessionState, IReadOnlySessionState interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use server side

> hidden field

to store path in client side code
like

in ur above code

```
 path = strip(path);
 alert(path);
 $("[id$='_hiddenPath']").val(path);
```

and this

```
Session["path"] = hiddenPath.Value
```

can be used in server side code also